# Fuzzy matching for a JSON string using Python

Tags: python, json

For my case, I have a Json format string like **{"name":"$name$","age":"$age$", "country":"UK"}**
I need to wrap the parameter with two "$" signs.
And in my Python program, I want to get the value which wrapped by "$", means I want to get **$name$** and **$age$** to a list. How can I use re or any other function to do the fuzzy matching?
Thanks

Comment: Get from where?

Comment: why not parse the json to a dictionary and just get the values of `name` and `age` directly?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: you could convert string to Python's dictionary `json.loads(your_string)` and use normal `for`-loop to get every `key,value` and check `value.startswith('$') and value.endswith('$')`

Comment: if you want to use `regex` then maybe you should search `\$[^\$]*\$`

Comment: The JSON string is from another list, I use json = list[1] to get the string.

Comment: @Anentropic that's bcs I don't know what key got the wraped "$" value. Here you can see name and age, but in my case, I don't know which fileds will be wrapped with "$", that's why I want to do a fuzzy match

Comment: @furas seems convert to a dict should work, let me have a try.

Comment: it doesn't matter what it has - you have to check only  $ at the beginning and at the end of string.

Comment: @furas The JSON string is from another list, I use a command like json = list[1] to get the string.

Comment: `data = json.loads(list[1])` to get Python's dictionary

Comment: @furas If I want to check $ at the beginning and at the end, do you mean I need to split the Json string to a new list? If so, this is what I tried as of now and worked. But I just want to see if there's any other way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert string to Python's dictionary `json.loads(your_string)` and use normal `for`-loop to get every `key,value` (`.items()`) or only `value` (`.values()`) and check `value.startswith('$') and value.endswith('$')`

```
import json

text = '{"name":"$name$","age":"$age$", "country":"UK"}'

data = json.loads(text)

result = []

#for key, value in data.items():
for value in data.values():
    #if value[0] == '$' and value[-1] == '$':
    if value.startswith('$') and value.endswith('$'):
        result.append(value)
        
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['$name$', '$age$']
```

---

If you want to do it with regex then you may need `'\$[^\$]*\$'`

It needs `\$` instead of `$` because `$` has special meaning in regex - it means end of line.

(I'm not sure if it needs `\` inside `[ ]`)

```
import re

text = '{"name":"$name$","age":"$age$", "country":"UK"}'

result = re.findall('\$[^\$]*\$', text)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
['$name$', '$age$']
```

Or you may needs `'\$.*?\$'` (with `?` for `greedy` search - for minimal string between two `$`)

If it has only chars then it could work also `\$[a-z]*\$`

Comment: Oh, that's it, I missed "." in my re.findall(r'\$*?\$', str).... so I just got nothing matched. using re.findall(r'\$.*?\$', str) will get what I need for fuzzy match.